# How do you call a virtual method stored in the base class and called by a class that inherits that base class twice?

Tags: c++, class, oop, multiple-inheritance

This code demonstrates the problem:

```
class Base
{
public:
    explicit Base(std::function<void()> const& printFunc) :
        _printFunc(printFunc)
    {
    }

    void print()
    {
        _printFunc();
    }
private:
   std::function<void()> _printFunc{};
private:
    virtual void _print() = 0; // If this line is commented out, then 
                               // `Subclass1::_print()` can be called.
};

class Subclass1 : public Base
{
public:
    explicit Subclass1() :
        Base([this]() { _print(); })
    {
    }
private:
    void _print() /*override*/
    {
        std::cout << "Subclass1\n";
    }
};

class Subclass2 : public Base, public Subclass1
{
public:
    using fromLowestSubclass = Base;
public:
    explicit Subclass2() :
        Base([this]() { _print(); }), Subclass1()
    {
    }
private:
    void _print() /*override*/
    {
        // Here is the problem:
        Subclass1::print(); // or: static_cast<Subclass1*>(this)->print(); 

        std::cout << "Subclass2\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Subclass2 sc2{};
    sc2.fromLowestSubclass::print();

    return 0;
}
```

In the `Subclass2::_print` method, the overriding `_print` method of `Subclass1` should be called, but instead the `Subclass1::print();` statement calls the current method again. This problem can be prevented if the statement `virtual void _print() = 0;` is commented out.
Why use of the virtual `_print` method prevents me from invoking the overloaded virtual method `Subclass1::_print` and what solution is there so that I do not have to do without virtual methods?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Base
{
    ....
private:
    virtual void _print() = 0; 
}
```

This means: you can override `_print`, but you can't call it, only `Base` has right to call it.

Now:

```
class Base
{
public:
    void print()
    {
        _printFunc();
    }
```

does that, it calls `_printFunc` as a virtual function, which matches current object instantiation. It doesn't meter how `print()` was invoked.

Adding `Subclass1::` as a prefix just changes name scope and doesn't have impact how method behaves. It has only have impact on name scope.

Now if virtual method has such prefix, then selecting name scope instruct compiler that you abandoning abstraction and you need to call specific method. In such case method is called without referring to a virtual table.

Double inheritance has no impact on this issue.

You can provide a helper method which you will be able to call from ancestor:

```
class Subclass1 : public Base
{
    ....
protected:
    void sub1_print() // not virtual
    {
        std::cout << "Subclass1\n";
    }
private:
    void _print() /*override*/
    {
        sub1_print();
    }
};

class Subclass2 : public Base, public Subclass1
{
    ....
private:
    void _print() /*override*/
    {
        sub1_print();

        std::cout << "Subclass2\n";
    }
};
```